# On further probing beyond quarks, will we uncover more fundamental particles?

Tags: particle-physics, quarks, beyond-the-standard-model

All matter as we know is made of protons neutrons and other particles which are fundamentally made of quarks. On further probation theoretically can we say quarks are made of more fundamental particles?